# How do I convert Mathematica syntax to latex?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, wolfram-mathematica

wolfram alpha accepts latex, but it does not export to latex,

it exports plaintext,rendered images and mathematica sytax.

Is there any javascript library that converts the output to latex?

Mathematica syntax:

```
Cell[BoxData[FormBox[TagBox[RowBox[List[FractionBox["1", "2"], " ", RowBox[List["(", RowBox[List[RowBox[List["4", " ", SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]]], "+", "x", "+", "2"]], ")"]]]], Identity, Rule[TagBoxNote, List[Rule["Hyperlink", "1/2 (2+x+4 x^2)"]]]], TraditionalForm]], "Output", Rule[PageWidth, 500], Rule[Magnification, 1], Rule[CellMargins, List[List[0, 0], List[0, 0]]], Rule[ShowCellBracket, False], Rule[FontFamily, "Bitstream Charter"], Rule[FontSize, 14], Rule[NumberSeparator, "\[ThinSpace]"]]
```

Latex syntax

```
2x^2+\frac{x}{2} +1
```

Comment: Not sure if allowed here or not, but [here](http://www.bugmenot.com/view/wolframalpha.com)

Comment: I would rather do it legally. Even so, it does not fix my problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can do it within Mathematica itself using [TeXForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html)

So you would do something like `ToExpression["\\frac{a}{b}", TeXForm]`